# JComboBox performing very slow

Tags: java, performance, user-interface, swing, jcombobox

I'm using JOptionPane and on that I have a tab. In tab I'm using JScrollPane to create a GUI having lots of text fields, lables and combo box.

The creation time of GUI is good but I'm dealing with the slow response of GUI, especially JComboBox. When I select any item, then it takes almost a second to display it.

I googled a lot and tried so many things but couldn't find a concrete solution.
My concern is to speed up the response of combo-box.

Please suggest
Thanks

Comment: Code samples and a machine / VM spec would be helpful... Oh and what is the data source for the combobox?

Comment: String [] values = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" };
Arrays.sort(values);
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(values);

Using JAVA 5 with Windows XP, i7 processor and 4GB RAM

Comment: Provide a working self-contained example.

Answer (score 1):

Without a working example there is not much specific advice we can give.  Some general tactics:

- Do some profiling to determine what part(s) of the program are preforming the slowest
- Look at memory usage and make sure you aren't at the edge of your max.
- Try cutting out parts of the application and see if it still has slow preformance